# Convert Json Object to another Json Object by converting types

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, types, nestjs

I was using redis with NestJS, and during my `hgetall`, i received

```
{
  isOpen: 'true',
  isPublic: 'true',
  cashPerPoint: '10',
  gameCount: '1',
  maxPlayers: '2',
  currentPlayers: 'bdc1,abc2',
  roomPlayers: '',
  gameStarted: 'false',
  gameOver: 'false',
  instantStart: 'false'
}
```

how can I convert/transform the types of values like this

```
{
  isOpen: true, //bool
  isPublic: true, //bool
  cashPerPoint: 10, //number
  gameCount: 1, //number
  maxPlayers: 2, //number
  currentPlayers: ['bdc1','abc2'], // string[]
  roomPlayers: [], //string[]
  gameStarted: false, //bool
  gameOver: false, //bool
  instantStart: false //bool
}
```

I would do it manually like this for the rest of the keys

```
data.currentPlayers = data.currentPlayers.length === 0 ? [] : data.currentPlayers.split(",");
data.roomPlayers = data.roomPlayers.length === 0 ? [] : data.roomPlayers.split(",");
```

but asking for a better solution, maybe something like this using Pipes or Serializers

```
const data: RoomInfoDTO = CONVERT(await this.asyncHGetAllFromRedis(key));
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to *type* the definitions or you want to convert the data type of the object you provided to the reference you provided?

Comment: I edited the question
i want to convert the data type of the object to the reference

Answer (score 1):

You can map the entries and use `parseInt`, check for `'true'` and `'false'`, and `String.prototype.split()` to parse the strings.

```js
const original = {
  isOpen: 'true',
  isPublic: 'true',
  cashPerPoint: '10',
  gameCount: '1',
  maxPlayers: '2',
  currentPlayers: 'bdc1,abc2',
  roomPlayers: '',
  gameStarted: 'false',
  gameOver: 'false',
  instantStart: 'false'
}

const parseValue = v => {
  const n = parseInt(v)
  if (!Number.isNaN(n)) return n
  if (v === 'true') return true
  if (v === 'false') return false
  if (v === '') return []
  return v.split(',')
}

const converted = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(original).map(([k, v]) => [k, parseValue(v)]))

console.log(converted)
```